# How run an spider sequentially to sites that use session in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, session, scrapy, ajaxform

I wanna scrape a web page  that first send an AjaxFormPost that open a session and next send an _SearchResultGridPopulate to populate a  control that I need to scrape, the  response is a json.

this is a fragment of my code:

```
def parse_AjaxFormPost(self, response):
        self.logger.info("parse_AjaxFormPost")
        page = response.meta['page']
        header = {
                'Accept':'*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Connection':'keep-alive',
                'Content-Length':'14',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Cookie':'ASP.NET_SessionId=gq4dgcsl500y32xb1n2ciexq',
                .
                .
                .
            }
        url = '<url>/Search/AjaxFormPost'
        cities = ['city1','city2',...]
        for city in cities:
            formData = {
                        'City':city
            }
            re = scrapy.FormRequest(
            url,
            formdata=formData,
            headers=header,
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.parse_GridPopulate
            )
            yield re  

def parse_GridPopulate(self,response):
        self.logger.info("parse_LookupPermitTypeDetails")
        url = '<url>/Search//_SearchResultGridPopulate?Grid-page=2&Grid-size=10&Grid-CERT_KEYSIZE=128&Grid-CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE=2048&Grid-HTTPS_KEYSIZE=128&Grid-HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE=2048'
        header = {
                'Accept':'*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Connection':'keep-alive',
                'Content-Length':'23',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Cookie':'ASP.NET_SessionId=gq4dgcsl500y32xb1n2ciexq',
                 .
                 .
                 .
        }
        formData = {
                    'page':'1',
                    'size':'10'
            }
        re = scrapy.FormRequest(
        url,
        formdata=formData,
        headers=header,
        dont_filter=True,
        callback=self.parse
        )

        yield re        


    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info("parse_permit")
        data_json = json.loads(response.body)
        for row in data_json["data"]:
            self.logger.info(row)
            item = RedmondPermitItem()
            item["item1"] = row["item1"]
            item["item2"] = row["item2"]
            yield item
```

The problem is that scrapy do request concurrent and when and the request in  parse_AjaxFormPost open a session so when pass to the  parse_LookupPermitTypeDetails I got the session of the last request do it in parse_AjaxFormPost. So if I have 10 cities at the end I got 10 times the information of the last city.

In settings I changed the configuration:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1
```

And it doesn't work. On other hand I thought in run the spider only for one city every time something like

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
# Your first spider definition
...
...
configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    cities = ['city1','city2',...]
        for city in cities:
            yield runner.crawl(MySpider1,city=city)
reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

Maybe this  can be the only one solution, but I'm not sure. I would like to create a procedure for every site with this characteristic.

Any suggestion about how solve that, is possible to achive this only configuring settings.

thanks in advance.

**Update1** 
I change the title because is important that is for sites that use session

Comment: did you able to solve it ? any solution ?

Comment: @agpt Well for my specific problem in that problem, the last code above, work for me, but it is an expensive solution, and depends on your problem, could be feasible or not. In my case for every city I record many items and hadn't many cities, but I think that is not a good solution if you need to call the spider for every page of a website.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of understanding how concurrency works, as this isn't parallelism you can still work sequentially, but between callbacks. I would suggest something like this:

```
def parse_AjaxFormPost(self, response):
    ...
    cities = ['city1','city2',...]
    formData = {
                'City':cities[0]
    }
    re = scrapy.FormRequest(
        url,
        formdata=formData,
        headers=header,
        dont_filter=True,
        callback=self.parse_remaining_cities,
        meta={'remaining_cities': cities[1:]}, # check the meta argument
    )
    yield re

def parse_remaining_cities(self, response):
    remaining_cities = response.meta['remaining_cities']
    current_city = remaining_cities[0]
    ...
    yield Request(
        ..., 
        meta={'remaining_cities': remaining_cities[1:]}, 
        callback=self.parse_remaining_cities)
```

This way you are doing one request at a time and in a row from city to city.

Comment: I review and test your answer, but I continue with problems with session, because I need that don't process one city until all request in depth related with current city finish to continue with next city